# How to get a custom Oracle function parameter definition

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

We need to get the Custom Function parameter list from Java jdbc.

we define the custom function in a package named **mypkg** .

I am using oracle as the database.

we can run command like **desc mypkg.customFunction** in the console.

but I want to know how to get similar information from java side.

Comment: @Abra I am using oracle.

Comment: Could you provide code snippets, so that it would be clearer what you're struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a stored function (and not a stored procedure), then method [getFunctionColumns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getFunctionColumns-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) will retrieve details of its parameters.

Consider the following code (which uses [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)).

Note that there appears to be a [bug](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2724009_1.html) in Oracle's JDBC driver where method `getFunctionColumns` retrieves the same parameter multiple times. The below code will display each parameter's details once only.

More explanations after the code.

```java
String url = "jdbc:oracle...";
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
    DatabaseMetaData dbmd = conn.getMetaData();
    ResultSet rs = dbmd.getFunctionColumns("mypkg", "<schema>", "customFunction", "%");
    String lastColumn = null;
    while (rs.next()) {
        String columnName = rs.getString(4);
        if (columnName != null  &&  !columnName.equals(lastColumn)) {
            String type;
            switch (rs.getShort(5)) { // parameter type (IN, OUT or IN-OUT)
                case DatabaseMetaData.functionColumnIn:
                    type = "IN";
                    break;
                case DatabaseMetaData.functionColumnInOut:
                    type = "IN OUT";
                    break;
                case DatabaseMetaData.functionColumnOut:
                    type = "OUT";
                    break;
                default:
                    type = "unknown";
            }
            System.out.printf("%s %s %s%n",
                              rs.getString(4),  // parameter name
                              type,             // parameter type
                              rs.getString(7)); // data type length
            lastColumn = columnName;
        }
    }
}
catch (SQLException xSql) {
    xSql.printStackTrace();
}
```

- I assume you know the JDBC connection URL that you need in order to connect to your Oracle database.
- First argument in call to method `getFunctionColumns` is the PL/SQL package name.
- Second argument in call to method `getFunctionColumns` is schema. Replace `<schema>` in the above code with the actual schema name of the owner of `mypkg`. If you don't know the schema then you can use null. Column 2 of the `ResultSet` returned by method `getFunctionColumns` contains the schema name.
- If `customFunction` is a stored procedure (and not a stored function), then you need method `getProcedureColumns`.